# Can start Nginx manually inside Docker container, but not automatically via CMD

Tags: docker, nginx, openshift

I'm deploying Nginx inside a Docker container (on OpenShift). If I use `ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "infinity"]` in my Dockerfile and then issue `nginx -g "daemon off;"` inside my container, Nginx starts up inside the container as expected. However, if I use `ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` in my Dockerfile, the container produces this error message at startup time:

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8000 failed (98: Address already in
>   use)

What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Can you include the entire Dockerfile in your question?  Do you have an ENTRYPOINT of any sort?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've now found a workaround. Starting `nginx` indirectly from `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/start.sh"]` works when `start.sh` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
nginx
sleep infinity
```

Strangely this invocation of `nginx` inside `start.sh` still produces the same error messages, but since it is followed by `sleep infinity` the `ENTRYPOINT` script now can succeed. Only if I do not invoke `nginx` at all, the error messages disappears but then Nginx does not run either. Strange indeed.

BTW, I'm using the Debian version of `nginx` and adjust the `user` directive in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in `Dockerfile` as well as several directory permissions for meeting OpenShift's requirements (where container images do not run as `root` but as random uids).

**UPDATE** The [root cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434624/openshift-runs-same-container-twice-when-it-should-run-two-different-ones-inside) turned out to be an error whereby the same container instance ran twice inside a pod. This (of course, in hindsight) led to the same server being started twice on the same node and hence to the error message about binding in the "second" container. I had always observed only the "second" container so far and therefore encountered the error. After resolving this, `ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` now works as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` and leave ENTRYPOINT as default.