# OpenShift runs same container twice when it should run two different ones inside pod

Tags: openshift

I want OpenShift 3.10 to create a pod (`console`) comprising two containers (`api` and `console`). The relevant description in the application template (under  `dc.spec.template.spec.containers`) for `DeploymentConfig` `console` looks like this:

```
containers:
- image: console:api
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  name: api
  terminationMessagePolicy: File
- image: console:console
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  name: console
  ports:
  - containerPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  terminationMessagePolicy: File
```

`oc describe is/console` looks good to me and reports the following (the  `BuildConfig`s for the two containers output to `ImageStreamTag`s `console:api` and `console:console` respectively):

```
api
  no spec tag
  * docker-registry.default.svc:5000/registry/console@sha256:96...66
console
  no spec tag
  * docker-registry.default.svc:5000/registry/console@sha256:8a...02
```

But `oc describe pods --selector deploymentconfig=console` reveals that the same image has been pulled twice and hence the same container runs twice inside the pod:

```
Successfully pulled image "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/registry/console@sha256:8a...02"
Successfully pulled image "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/registry/console@sha256:8a...02"
```

How can I ensure that the pod indeed comprises the two distinct containers? And why is the [image stream tag](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#image-stream-tag) `console:api` apparently at times not referring to image `96...66` but also to `8a...02`, contrary to what `os describe is/console` suggests?

**UPDATE** The mismatch is also apparent in `oc describe dc/console`, which  indicates that both image stream tags `console:api` and `console:console` apparently have been resolved to the same container image `8a...02`:

```
Containers:
 api:
  Image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/registry/console@sha256:8a...02
 console:
  Image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/registry/console@sha256:8a...02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change to `dc.spec.triggers` seems to have resolved the situation:

```
- type: ConfigChange
- imageChangeParams:
    automatic: true
    containerNames:
    - api
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: console:api
      namespace: registry
  type: ImageChange
- imageChangeParams:
    automatic: true
    containerNames:
    - console
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: console:console
      namespace: registry
  type: ImageChange
```

Previously, there was only a single `imageChangeParams` for `console:console`. The pod now comprises the two distinct containers.